# Docking *inside* an editor

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a document type which has multiple presentations. Say I want to display the document in an RCP editor with a customizable subset of those presentations, in a layout chosen by the user.

One option that has come up is docking-like behavior for the panels *inside* an individual editor, with drag-and-drop, resizing, closing, maybe rollover and floating.

Clearly this would need usability testing, but my question here is of feasibility.

Are there any existing libraries or e4 plans to support behavior like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the eclipse magazine 03-2010 is an article about that stuff from lars vogel and others. you can find it using Google with 'Lars Vogel "widget explorer"'. it is written in German. 
you can also download the [widget explorer](http://it-republik.de/zonen/magazine/ausgaben/psfile/source_file/63/Quellen_Wi4ba897dbf3478.zip). the article says that the widget explorer is only a simple example (it supports moving with dnd, color chosing, minimize and edit). with the [wazaabi project](http://wazaabi.org/) or e4 could be done much more.